# Is thumbnail image mandatory for Apple generic type wallet pass

Tags: ios, xcode, wallet, passkit

I have been working with wallet pass as Mentioned in the apple pass creation design document
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW4

If i remove thumbnail image from generic type pass the pk pass file is not valid.

So, Is thumbnail image mandatory for generic pass?

Comment: It should be valid - hook your phone up to a Mac and review the logs when you try to install the pass.  It will tell you why it is failing.  Or post a link to a .pkpass bundle.

Comment: @passkit If i have thumbnail image then the pass is Valid. Even i couldn't open in mac itself.

Comment: What do the logs show when you add it.  I don’t know how you are compiling your pass, it could be failing for another reason.  You need the log to be sure.

Comment: @PassKit Do we need to include manifest.json file for image handling?

Comment: Yes - of course! The manifest needs to list every file present in the bundle. If there is a file without a manifest entry or a manifest entry without a file, then it will fail to load (and this would be clearly stated in the log).